# Handle PostgreSQL transaction errors in GDALVectorTranslate

Tags: c++, postgresql, postgis, gdal

In c++ I'm using the GDAL library for importing geo-spatial files into Postgres/PostGIS.

The GDAL library will create a table in the Postgres database and insert the data. But I can't figure out how to handle errors during the inserting of data.

I'm using GDALVectorTranslate https://gdal.org/api/gdal_utils.html#gdal__utils_8h_1aa176ae667bc857ab9c6016dbe62166eb

If an Postgres error occurs the error text will be outputted and the program continues to run. I would like to handle these Postgres errors.

An error could be:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe5 0x20 0x46
```

For now I let my program count the rows in the destination table and if zero then assume error. But that doesn't work if appending to an existing table.

```cpp
    auto *dst = (GDALDataset *) GDALVectorTranslate(nullptr, pgDs, 1, &sourceDs, opt, &bUsageError);

    if (dst == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! Couldn't create table" << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        OGRLayer *layer = dst->GetLayerByName(altName);
        // Here the rows are counted
        if (layer->GetFeatureCount() == 0) {
            std::cout << "ERROR! Insert failed" << std::endl;
            return FALSE;
        }
        std::cout << "   Imported";
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own error handler to log and count the underlying errors:

```
struct {/*members for handling errors*/} ctx;
static void myErrorHandler(CPLErr e, CPLErrorNum n, const char* msg) {
   ctx *myctx = (ctx*)CPLGetErrorHandlerUserData();
   /* do something with ctx to log and increment error count */
}

int myTranslateFunc() {
   ctx myctx; //+initialization
   CPLPushErrorHandlerEx(&myErrorHandler,&myctx);
   auto *dst = (GDALDataset *) GDALVectorTranslate(nullptr, pgDs, 1, &sourceDs, opt, &bUsageError);
   CPLPopErrorHandler();
   //inspect myctx for potential errors
}
```